# Prove that if $\mathscr P(X)$ is a subset of $\mathscr P(Y)$ then $X$ is a subset of $Y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Seems obvious:

> Prove that if $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is a subset of $\mathscr{P}(Y)$, then $X$ is a subset of $Y$.

How to write a formal undeniable proof?  Here $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$, the collection of all subsets of $X$.

Comment: It's bad form not to use the body of the Question to formulate the complete statement of the problem, relying as here on the title to carry that burden.  I suspect that with a little more effort in stating the problem, perhaps including the definition of power set, you would discover the "formal undeniable proof" yourself.

Comment: I think what hardmath was trying to say was a lot of the time, it is helpful when trying to prove something to write down your assumptions.  In this case, our assumption is that $\mathcal{P}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(Y)$.  But what does that mean?  Well, it means every element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$.  But what does an element of a power set look like?  Then you would go back to the definition of power set.  Then once you've done this, the proof usually becomes clear.  It's a good habit to form, because it empowers you to prove a lot of statements on your own.

Comment: Having said that, if you ever get stuck and feel like you cannot move forward when trying to prove something, there's no shame in asking for help.  Actually, in my opinion, there's shame in not asking for help when you know you really need it.  So basically, please continue to ask questions when you need help, but also consider (if you don't do this already) reviewing your assumptions and related definitions to try to prove statements on your own first, because chances are you can do it!

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \in X$.  Then $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{P}(X)$.  But $\mathcal{P}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(Y)$ implies $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$.  But this implies $x \in Y$, so $X \subseteq Y$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

We have $X \in \mathcal P(X) \subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$, so $X \in \mathcal P(Y)$, which means $X \subseteq Y$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

$X\in\mathcal{P}(X)\subset\mathcal{P}(Y)$ so $X$ is a subset of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(X)$ is a subset of $P(Y)$, what this means is that every subset of $X$ is also a subset of $Y$. Therefore the union of all subsets of $X$ is itself a subset of $Y$. But the union of all subsets of $X$ is $X$ itself, and therefore $X\subseteq Y$.